# EXTJS 4.2.1 Legend not fitting completely in panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-architect

I have made a few piecharts and each piechart has its own panel. The problem is that the legends of each pie charts are not fully displaying they are being cut off as there is not much width available on the page.

is there any properties that allows the legend to be fitted in to a particular area or maybe the legend is not fully written in 1 line but split into 2 lines so that it doesnt require so much width.

currently I only have this code

legend {
position : 'right'
}

Comment: Could you provide a working Sencha Fiddle?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @PeterKoltai 
I do not have a working Sencha Fiddle that i can share 
I have made a piechart using Ext.chart.chart 
I have put that piechart inside of the widget panel 
Now i want to make a legent for this panel but inside another panel and put these two panel as a vbox formation 

How would i make a legend and add that into a panel then put these 2 panels as a vbox layout i know i have to add these 2 panels inside a panel which will hold them together

Answer (score 1):

You can use **legend: { docked: 'right'}** instead of using legend { position: 'right' } by using this you will be able to set the legend to a particular area(ie: left, right, top, and bottom).
Here is the working solution - [enter link description here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3moi)

Comment: That doesnt work because the problem is the legends are not fitting in the specific panel size they are overflowing out